# How to implement Action Listener in a GUI class?

Tags: java

```
public class ConverterGUI  {
   // You should add ActionListener for the Convert button


private  String[] units={"Mile","Yard","Foot"};
private JFrame frame;


public ConverterGUI() {

    initializeFrame();
}


private void initializeFrame() {
    frame = new JFrame("Length Converter");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    initUI();
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 300));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}


private void initUI() {
    JTextField inputField = new JTextField(15);
    inputField.setBounds(60, 50, 200, 30);
    JLabel kilometer = new JLabel("Kilometer");
    kilometer.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.BOLD, 20));
    kilometer.setBounds (300, 50, 200, 30);

    JTextField outputField = new JTextField(15);
    outputField.setEditable(false);
    outputField.setLocation(10, 200);

    outputField.setBounds(60, 100, 200, 30);
    JComboBox outputUnit = new JComboBox<String>();
    for (String u : units) {
        outputUnit.addItem(u);
    }

    outputUnit.setBounds (300, 100, 60, 30);
    JButton convertButton = new JButton("Convert!");




    convertButton.setBounds (60, 150, 200, 30);
    convertButton.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.BOLD, 20));
    frame.add(inputField);
    frame.add(kilometer);
    frame.add(outputField);
    frame.add(outputUnit);
    frame.add(convertButton);
}

//Here you have to implement the action listener..

}
```

Here is a GUI class from my teacher and he wants me to add an action listener.

// You should add ActionListener for the Convert button

//Here you have to implement the action listener..

These two lines are his requirement.

But he already created a button called converButton, and all the tutorials I found on net are telling me to create a class to implement ActionListener.

However the convertButton is inside a method, so I don't know what to do now or where to implement the ActionListener.

Comment: adding action listener: `button.addActionListener(listener);`; implementing: `class MyListener implements ActionListener { @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) { ...} }`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class inside another class.  This is called an inner class.

The simplest form would look like this.

```
public class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Your action listener code goes here

    }

}
```

You have to add these two imports at the beginning of the main class.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
```

To invoke an instance of the MyActionListener class, you would code the following line in the `initUI` method.

```
convertButton.addActionListener(new MyActionListener());
```

The inner class is just like any other Java class.  You can pass parameters to a constructor if you want.  You usually don't have to pass parameters to an inner class constructor, as an inner class can access any class variables or methods in the main class.

For even simpler action listeners, you can create an inline anonymous class.

```
convertButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

These should only be used for really simple action listeners.

In general, it's best to have separate action listener classes in separate files and packages.  But sometimes, it makes sense to have an inline action listener class.  Usually when there are too many parameters to pass through a constructor.

I hope this helps.  Read up on anonymous and inner classes.

Comment: Yes, it helps a lot! Thank you!

Comment: Another question is, should I also need to add a listener for JComboBox(which is the outputUnit)? There are 3 option  for users to choose. I want to know which option the user chose.

Comment: @commanderspring: No.  The action is the convert button.  You can get the JComboBox selection before you do the actual conversion in the convert button action listener code.

Comment: But I want to use the result from ComboBox inside the action listener.
Like if user pick Yard, and I convert Km to Yard in the action listener(actionperformed).
How would you do that?  I can't connect action listener and ComboBox, they just like two different thing.